# Excel - Pivot table where multiple fields are seen as a single field

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have data similar to the below

```
Forename | Surname | ID | Role
-------------------------------
Jo       | Bloggs  | 1  | A
Jo       | Bloggs  | 1  | B
Jo       | Bloggs  | 1  | C
Mary     | Bloggs  | 2  | A
Mary     | Bloggs  | 2  | B
Mary     | Bloggs  | 2  | C
Mary     | Bloggs  | 2  | D
Mary     | Bloggs  | 2  | E
```

The pivot would result in the below

```
Details       | A | B | C | D | E
1 Jo Bloggs   | X | X | X |   |
1 Mary Bloggs | X | X | X | X | X
```

Comment: Could you add a helper column concatating ID, Forename and Surname then pivot on that?

Comment: In hindsight yes but I might need to expand my answer. Would there be no opportunity to have the columns separated out?